# Where to define static const member variables of a template class

Tags: c++, templates

According to this [question's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2605520/368599) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605520/c-where-to-initialize-static-const/2605559#2605559):

`According to the standards you must define i` *(which is a static const member)* `outside of the class definition`

... but if I do that for static const member variables of a template class which are themselves generic, then I get linking errors (similar to getting linking errors if the template code is in a separate compilation unit). If I define them in the header, the linking errors disappear (I asked whether it was OK to define them in a `generic` way in the first place in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6397330/368599)).

**Is what I am doing, safe?** Below is one of the definitions of a static const member variable which is in the header.

```
  template<typename T, unsigned int T_Size> 
  const Vector<T, T_Size> Vector<T, T_Size>::Zero = Vector<T, T_Size>(0);
```

Comment: Can you post a complete example of failure? This problem is sensitive to the details. You should put the generic static const member initialization in the header in any case. You can also request explicit instantiation of a template in a translation unit via `template Vector<int, 4>;`.

Comment: @Kerrek: Just put the definition in the question in a .cpp instead of the header.

Comment: @Xeo: Works fine for me, I can't reproduce the linker error.

Comment: @Kerrek: Included the header with the template in multiple translation units?

Comment: @Kerrek, if I do explicit instantiation, then there are no linking errors, but since this Vector class is generic that would not be a solution. As for the error, if you put the definition in the `*.cpp` file _without_ explicit instantiation of the template and then try to instantiate one in another compilation unit, you will get the linking error.

Comment: @Samaursa: Right, the templated static const member initialization must be available to all consumers, so it has to be in the header. It cannot just be in one single .cpp file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Static data members of a class template have to be defined in a header file. Only when you are defining static members of an *explicitly specialized* template, you have to define them in an implementation file.

In other words, the rule is the same as for member functions of class templates.

Answer (score 2):

Since a *complete* definition of the template is needed in every translation unit, yes, this is the way to go.