# typedefing non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to access a template parameter outside of a class. I usually do this as follows:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
  typedef typename T T;
}

A<int>::T;
```

I would like to be able to do the same for non-type template parameters. This doesn't work:

```
template <int T>
class A
{
  typedef typename T T;
}

A<3>::T;
```

I will clarify why I need this. I want to define a second class as follows:

```
template <class C>
class B
{
  static int func() {return C::T;}
}

B<A<3> >::func();
```

What is the correct way to do this?
Thank you very much.

Comment: `class` is interchangeable with `typename`, `int` is not. Also, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually, you cannot use `typename` in either code since `T` isn’t a dependent name, and you cannot redefine `T` either.

Comment: `typename` before unqualified names, such as the dependent unqualified name `T`, is not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `T` is not a type name and you cannot `typedef` it. It is an `int` value and, if you want to access it as a static member of the class, you need a static member `int`. Seems like what you really want is this:

```
template <int T>
class A
{
  public:
    static const int x = T;
};

doSomething(A<5>::x);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a value, and not a type, so perhaps:

```
template <int T>
class A
{
  static const int param = T;
};
```

And then you can access it as `A<42>::param`. Not that it helps much, unless A is itself used as a template parameter somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

in the second case, `T` is not a type, it's an `int` value. Therefore you should define it as a <s>`const int` or</s> `static const int` value.

```
template <int T>
class A {
    static const int T = T;
};
```

Note that it is customary to use `T` for types (in particular when the template is monadic, since there is no ambiguity on the type), and other names for constants, usually a more meaningful name, for instance `SIZE` or preferably `Size` (all caps symbols are best used for macros).

```
template <int Param>
class A {
    static const int param = Param;
};
```

See other SO questions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397330/defining-static-const-variables-of-a-template-class)) for the use of `static const` values in the context of a template definition.